# Summary of Pumping Lemma Application

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

For my own understanding I would like to summarize how to use the pumping lemma to show that a language is not regular. The pumping lemma is defined as follows.

> **Pumping lemma** If $A$ is a regular language, then there is a number $p$ (the pumping length) where if $s$ is any string in $A$ of length at least
> $p$, then $s$ may be divided into three pieces, $s = xyz$, satisfying the
> following conditions:
>
> 1. for each $i≥0, xy^i z∈A$,
> 2. $|y|>0$,
> 3. and $|xy|≤p$.

Is the following an accurate summary of how to use the pumping lemma to show that a language is not regular: Take a specific string that belongs to $A$ (of length at least $p$), repeat ("pump") a section of that string (that has nonzero length), and if the resulting string does not belong to $A$ then $A$ is not a regular language?

Comment: Point 1, The pumping lemma is its own summary. Point 2, it is still helpful to come up with your own summary, and it seems that you interpret your summary consistently with the pumping lemma. Point 3, here is my summary, a language with an "un-pumpable" long-enough string is not regular. Here "un-pumpable" means however the string is split, pumping the middle part down once or up many times may result  in a string that is not in the language.